# Get JSON data based on the item I clicked ionic ionic 3

Tags: html, json, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

So when I click the image I want it to go to a page where it shows all the like the title and other information I'm pretty sure this was going to work but I don't know why its not Please Help me!

The problem is that it's showing this "cannot read property title"

home.html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>Home</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <ion-searchbar
  [(ngModel)]="myInput"
  [showCancelButton]="shouldShowCancel"
  (ionInput)="onInput($event)"
  (ionCancel)="onCancel($event)">
</ion-searchbar>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="column" *ngFor="let item of items">
      <img [src]="item.thumbnailUrl" alt="Snow" style="width:100%;border-radius: 4px;" (click)="viewItem(item.id)">
      {{item.title}}
    </div>
  </div>


</ion-content>
```

Home.ts

```
   import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { HttpClient } from '../../../node_modules/@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from '../../../node_modules/rxjs/Observable';
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  public items: any;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,public http: HttpClient) {
      this.getData();
  }

  getData(){
    let Url = 'www.dontworryaboutitJustHelpmePlease!IwillLoveYou.com/api';
    let data: Observable<any> = this.http.get(Url);
    data.subscribe(result =>{
      this.items = result;
    }); 
  }
  viewItem(item){
    this.navCtrl.push('TvshowPage', { item: item })
  }
}

The page thats getting the information ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-tvshow',
  templateUrl: 'tvshow.html',
})
export class TvshowPage {
  item: any;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public params:NavParams) {
      this.item = params.get('item');
  }
```

}

The page thats getting the information html

```
    <ion-header>

      <ion-navbar>
        <ion-title></ion-title>
      </ion-navbar>

    </ion-header>


<ion-content padding>
      <p>{{item.title}}</p>
</ion-content
```

>

Please help me hope this makes sense.

ps: I WILL LOVE you FOREVER IF yOU HELP ME!

Comment: (click)=viewItem(item) pass item and you just pass id so you are not able to get title just pass item and  viewItem(item){ console.log(item)} here you will get particular item data instead of item.id

Comment: Wait how do i do that can you explain a little bit more

Comment: first just pass item and show me your logs over viewItem method

Comment: ummm i just tried it and it worked thank you so much!!!! I LOVE YOU FOREVER

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In here you are passing `item.id` from UI try passing item instant of item.id. Your code should looks like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="column" *ngFor="let item of items">
      <img [src]="item.thumbnailUrl" alt="Snow" style="width:100%;border-radius: 4px;" (click)="viewItem(item)">
      {{item.title}}
    </div>
  </div>



viewItem(item){
    console.log(item); //It will show you every items from your object that you passed. now you can access anything by using item.
    this.navCtrl.push('TvshowPage', { item: item })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(click)=viewItem(item)
```

in html

You just pass item.id that's why are not able to get title so you have to pass item over click method

```
viewItem(item){ 
 console.log(item)
 }
```

in javascript

here you will get particular item data instead of item.id